# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "pdf_conversion" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to add in a conversion model that is referenced in the fileurl model that calls my customuser model.  But for some reason, I get the following error when loading the admin panel.

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /admin/pdf/conversion/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "pdf_conversion" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "pdf_conversion"
                                          ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1697, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 736, in get_changelist_instance
    return ChangeList(
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.get_results(request)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 235, in get_results
    result_count = paginator.count
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 97, in count
    return c()
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 412, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 519, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 504, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/pdf/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "pdf_conversion" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "pdf_conversion"
                                          ^
```

And these are my models

```
class Conversion(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='user', null=True, blank=False)
    conversion_id = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=200)
    api_domain = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)


class FileUrlVal(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    tool = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    expired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    conversion = models.ForeignKey(Conversion, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Please note, I have already deleted all the migration files and tried to re run it (python manage.py makemigrations python manage.py migrate), it migrates fine.  Just fails when I try and load it in the admin. My admin call looks like so

```
class ConversionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'api_domain',
    )
```

And when I run `manage.py showmigrations --verbosity 2 pdf` I get  `pdf  [X] 0001_initial (applied at 2021-10-31 02:17:08)` 
I would appreciate any help

Comment: When you deleted all migration files what steps did you perform to "re run it"? Can you add the output of `manage.py showmigrations --verbosity 2 pdf` to your question?

Comment: @IainShelvington Correct,  when I do that, it shows this `pdf
 [X] 0001_initial (applied at 2021-10-31 02:17:08)
`

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted you migration files, do you have them in version control so you can recover them? You should make additional migration files when you make model changes

Comment: @IainShelvington I was able to restore the old migrations and that did not work, the main issue was that my database was corrupted.  I tried a restored version none corrputed and all worked well. Thanks for pointing out the issue